# Combining matrices in r

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am trying to read-in edgelists from two different tab separated files, convert them into adjacency matrices with a funcation in igraph, then combine these matrices into a 3d array I need as input for another function (qaptest in package sna).  I have gotten most of the way there but the last array statement to combine them is not producing the expected results.  This is shown in the run/output below.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
>obs <- read.table("002-obs.txt",sep="\t", header=FALSE)
>per <- read.table("002-per.txt",sep="\t", header=FALSE)
# load igraph
>mper <- AdjacencyFromEdgelist(per, check.full = TRUE)
>mper
$adjacency
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    7    3
[2,]    7    0    4
[3,]    0    0    0

$nodelist
[1] 7314 9539 9794
>mobs <- AdjacencyFromEdgelist(obs, check.full = TRUE)
>mobs
$adjacency
       [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
[1,]   0.00 155.25 55.75
[2,] 258.75   0.00 77.50
[3,]   0.00   0.00  0.00

$nodelist
[1] 7314 9539 9794

> dat<-array(c(mper,mobs),c(3,3,2))
> dat
, , 1

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] Numeric,9 Integer,3 Numeric,9
[2,] Integer,3 Numeric,9 Integer,3
[3,] Numeric,9 Integer,3 Numeric,9

, , 2

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] Integer,3 Numeric,9 Integer,3
[2,] Numeric,9 Integer,3 Numeric,9
[3,] Integer,3 Numeric,9 Integer,3
```

Comment: Please show expected results.

Comment: `mper` was a list with a single item, so it's not a matrix. Likewise `mobs`. Try pulling the items out with the `[[` function:   `dat<-array(c(mper[[1]],mobs[[1]]),c(3,3,2))`

Comment: Expected result was mper and mobs stacked, and the suggested command did it.  I don't get why mper and mobs were single item lists.  They printed as matrices, no?  Anyway thanks!